# show row only 100 times PHP

Tags: php

How can I make a limit of showing the results? I need to limit it for 100 views.

In DB I have:

```
ID|NAME|PAGE|COUNT|DATE
```

In count I want to count untill 100 and then stop showing that ID. I could do it with count < 100. And then update the specific ID. I could get records with less than 100 views, but I couldn't manage to update count on the specific ID.

Row is showed with:

php code:

```
foreach($bannerGroups[0] as $ban) {
        echo '<li class="right1">'.$ban->html().'</li>';       
}
```

But I just don't know where to put the update in there. I tried, but all I got was to update only one ID. But it shows 4 on one page and randomizes them on refresh. So I don't know what to do.

Also I would like to say I am only learning php. Sorry for all the mess.

Code at http://pastebin.com/A9hJTPLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show all banners that have been previously-displayed less than 100 times?

If that's right, you can just add that to your `WHERE` clause:

```
$bannerResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE page='cat' WHERE `COUNT` < 100");
```

To update them all, you can either run a query while displaying each individual banner, or "record" the `id` of each and run a single query at the end, like:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($bannerGroups[0] as $ban) {
    $ids[] = $ban['ID']; // record the ID; don't know how Banner
                         // class works, assuming uses indexes; maybe ID() method?
    echo '<li class="right1">'.$ban->html().'</li>';
}
...
mysql_query('UPDATE table SET `COUNT` = `COUNT` + 1 WHERE ID IN (' . join(',', $ids) . ')');
```

**UPDATE**:
Based off of a comment, your `Banner` class doesn't have a method to retrieve the individual banner's `ID`. In this case, you can record the `ID` values when you're building your banners array:

```
$ids = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($bannerResult)) {
    $banners[] = new Banner($row);
    $ids[] = $row['ID']; // record the ID
}
// update the `count` on each record:
mysql_query('UPDATE table SET `COUNT` = `COUNT` + 1 WHERE ID IN (' . join(',', $ids) . ')');
```

Comment: thats funny you made same mistake as me 2x `WHERE`

Comment: I used your method, but i get this error: Cannot use object of type Banner as array in. Also i did put update before last two {

Comment: @user1531524 Yeah - that's expected; your `$ban` variables, which comes from `$bannerGroups`, which comes from `$banners` - it is of type `Banner`; I don't know how your class works, but I assume you can get the `ID` value for each individual banner. Maybe you have a function in Banner named `ID()`, or `getValue('ID');`?

Comment: Sorry, but i dont. Is there any other way?

Comment: @user1531524 You don't have a way to get the banner's `ID` from the `Banner` class? My recommendation would be to update the class to allow something like that; however, I'll try to update my answer real quick to help your current situation.

Comment: i posted another part of script here:  pastebin.com/Mt7AKMnX  from there i guess u can get the id to show, but i cant figure out how to record it.

Comment: @user1531524 Your current `Banner` class doesn't have a way to retrieve the `ID`; I modified it here http://pastebin.com/7n9FSq1A . To get the `ID`, or any other value of the current banner, you can use `$ban->getValue('ID');`; alternatively, you could make `$data` public and use `$ban->data['ID']`.

Comment: This updates all the ids for me: mysql_query("UPDATE dataa SET COUNT = COUNT + 1 WHERE id = $ban->getValue('ID')");

Answer (score 1):

sorry, but I got your question wrong...

first you have to insert a new sql-column like "viewcount" to the db...
on every read, you have to increment the value in viewcount...

for that behaviour (because, mysql does not allow sub-selects on update-clause on the same table), you have to fetch the results from db, as you do that, and pass all the primary-keys of the records to an array...
after the view-logic you have to fire up a query like:

```
UPDATE foo SET viewcount = viewcount + 1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6...,100);
```

where the IN-clause can be easily generated using your primary-keys-array with "implode(',', $arr);"

hope this helps.

Comment: ah i forgot... your initial select query SHOULD contain the viewcount-prop, too...

"SELECT * FROM table WHERE page='cat' AND viewcount < 100" as Peter Szymkowski pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bannerResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE page='cat' AND `count`<100");
```

Answer (score 0):

@newfurniturey figured it out. in each `foreach($banneruGroups added: $ids = $ban->getValue('id');` and then `mysql_query("UPDATE dataa SET COUNT = COUNT + 1 WHERE id = '$ids'");` but is there any way to update them by adding query only once? And if the id is showed already 100 times i get `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in.` Any idea how to fix it? I have 4 ids in DB . If one of them already have 100 views (count) then i get error!

Answer (score -1):

Try to limit your data source for 100 items.
It's like `OFFSET x LIMIT 100` in MySQL/PostgreSQL query or `TOP 100` in MSSQL.